# how to get the time gap more than 24 hours in php

Tags: php, time

i have to variable `$a` and `$b` `$a= 645:00:00` and `$b = 555:00:00` . i want to get the difference of the two time value .(both `$a` and `$b` are string value).how do is get out put as `90:00:00` using PHP

Already try code

```
  $totaltimeholiday = (strtotime($a) - strtotime($b));
  $hours = sprintf('%02d', intval($totaltimeholiday / 3600));
  $seconds_remain = ($totaltimeholiday - ($hours * 3600)); 
  $minutes = sprintf('%02d', intval($seconds_remain / 60));   
  $seconds = sprintf('%02d' ,($seconds_remain - ($minutes * 60)));
  $totaltimeholidayfinal = $hours.':'.$minutes.':'.$seconds;
```

but it return only `00:00:00`

Comment: $a and $b value under 24 hours its work fine.

Comment: `645` and `555` are not valid hours

Comment: $a and $b are calculated sum value .it not single time

Comment: some how i need calculate the time difference in both variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your two times aren't valid times you can't use `strtotime`. But you can achieve what you need in a simple way as follows,

```
<?php

$a = "645:00:00"; 
$b = "555:00:00";

list ($hour1, $min1, $sec1) = explode(':', $a);
list ($hour2, $min2, $sec2) = explode(':', $b);

$sumHour = sprintf('%02d', $hour1 - $hour2);
$sumMin = sprintf('%02d', $min1 - $min2);
$sumSec = sprintf('%02d', $sec1 - $sec2);

echo $sumHour.':'.$sumMin.':'.$sumSec;

?>
```

The result is,

> 90:00:00